# How OrientDB Studio Code Works?

Tags: orientdb

I have a question regarding the way the OrientDB studio works.

When I build my own web application to access the OrientDB database, I need to enable CORS and then it works, but how comes that the OrientDB studio app works without having to enable CORS?

That's really puzzling me because I'd like to reuse the code logic of the OrientDB Studio app in my own application and it does not work like the OrientDB Studio app.

Also, it seems that the OrientDB Studio app is using the REST API of OrientDB, not the JavaScript API (orientdb-api.js). Am I right?

Is there any documentation I could read to get a full understanding of how the Studio works?

Regards,
Jeremie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable CORS because your app it is outside the domain of ODB. if you are running it in localhost is `http://localhost:2480`.

So if you make a request from a different domain the browser stops you if the server has CORS disabled.

Studio starts as a plugin inside ODB http (`http://localhost:2480/studio/index.html`) so is allowed to do request without enabling CORS.

If you do not want to enable CORS you can put your html and js under the www directory in
the $ORIENTDB_HOME distribution.

There is no documentation about Studio Code. You can browse it here https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-studio if you need some further information you can ask me as i'm the main maintainer of Studio :D

I can tell you that it does not use the orientdb-api.js as it uses angular.js. 
I advice you to not use orientdb-api.js but uses directly the REST api
with JQuery/Angular.

Comment: Hello,

I really appreciate your quick reply!

This will be of a great help. 

I now understand the idea that the OrientDB studio is a plugin and therefore does not need to have CORS enabled, so this clarifies.

I'm now convinced not to go with the OrientDB JavaScript API and will stick with the REST API and JQuery and/or AngularJS.

Comment: I really appreciate your offer to help me with any question regarding the OrientDB Studio app. Would it be possible to have your contact information, please?

My email is jeremie@rsdv.ca.

Regards,
Jeremie